# Расчетное поле после группировки

Tags: python, pandas

Нужно сгруппировать данные и вывести расчетное поле 'price_u'. Знаю, что можно сделать через доп столбец:

```
pandas_df['price_u'] = df['price']/df['quantity'] 
pandas_df.groupby('good')['price_u'].max().drop_duplicates()
pandas_df.drop('price_u', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

но хотелось бы сделать по-человечески.

Comment: [Можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь методом [.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
In [348]: (df.eval("price_u = price / quantity")
             .groupby('good')
             ['price_u']
             .max()
             .drop_duplicates())
Out[348]:
good
aaa    7.575
bbb    0.825
Name: price_u, dtype: float64
```

или [.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
In [349]: (df.assign(price_u=df['price']/df['quantity'])
             .groupby('good')
             ['price_u']
             .max()
             .drop_duplicates())
Out[349]:
good
aaa    7.575
bbb    0.825
Name: price_u, dtype: float64
```

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [347]: df
Out[347]:
  good  price  quantity
0  aaa   10.1         2
1  aaa   20.2         5
2  aaa   30.3         4
3  bbb    1.1         2
4  bbb    2.2         5
5  bbb    3.3         4
```